# NVRAM Showing Questionable Payload Variables... Can anyone verify if this is normal?

Tags: startup, macos, nvram

I used the terminal command in macOS 'nvram -xp':

```
    student:~ admin$ nvram -xp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ALS_Data</key>
    <data>
    AKs=
    </data>
    <key>LocationServicesEnabled</key>
    <data>
    AQ==
    </data>
    <key>SmcFlasherResult</key>
    <data>
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
    </data>
    <key>SystemAudioVolume</key>
    <data>
    VA==
    </data>
    <key>SystemAudioVolumeDB</key>
    <data>
    6w==
    </data>
    <key>Test_ALS_Data</key>
    <data>
    AQA=
    </data>
    <key>backlight-level</key>
    <data>
    2Qo=
    </data>
    <key>bluetoothActiveControllerInfo</key>
    <data>
    j4KsBQAAAAAzFEjXBbzp6g==
    </data>
    <key>bluetoothInternalControllerInfo</key>
    <data>
    j4KsBQAAMxRI1wW86eo=
    </data>
    <key>boot-gamma</key>
    <data>
    EAYAAN+cAAAAAAAAwgAAAAAAAAAMAAEGTwQDDl8MySdZLFRQ5FpXXFtnXXYff6OMHJYr
    rUC5scSGz3TQ99j995Tz//zo+A4AAQesBAMOFwtQQxZGV1/CYuGHoIenneyeqabNp667
    scCxxXvKM8+w0vXWmdq66T3q/fRw9f/80voQAAIIJwQEEO8JTz6PMxJK1zxVV5RIIoh4
    biaagXqttECR7rp1lbDABZ3zzmaru+zuzf32n9v++YTh/vuH6P/9//I=
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload0</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPjQ3MUE4QUI0LUVB
    NjUtNEQzMC1BM0YzLURENjhFMEEwMjRBNTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMHMxPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XEVGSVxBUFBMRVxV
    UERBVEVSU1xTTUNcTWFjLTdERjIxQ0IzRUQ2OTc3RTUuc21jPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjwvYXJyYXk+AA==
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload0-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgABAAAAKAAAAAAAAAAA
    QAYAAAAAALSKGkdl6jBNo/PdaOCgJKUCAgQEZgBcAEUARgBJAFwAQQBQAFAATABFAFwA
    VQBQAEQAQQBUAEUAUgBTAFwAUwBNAEMAXABNAGEAYwAtADcARABGADIAMQBDAEIAMwBF
    AEQANgA5ADcANwBFADUALgBzAG0AYwAAAH//BAA=
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload1</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPjQ3MUE4QUI0LUVB
    NjUtNEQzMC1BM0YzLURENjhFMEEwMjRBNTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMHMxPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XEVGSVxBUFBMRVxV
    UERBVEVSU1xTTUNcZmxhc2hlcl9iYXNlLnNtYzwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2FycmF5
    PgA=
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload1-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgABAAAAKAAAAAAAAAAA
    QAYAAAAAALSKGkdl6jBNo/PdaOCgJKUCAgQEVgBcAEUARgBJAFwAQQBQAFAATABFAFwA
    VQBQAEQAQQBUAEUAUgBTAFwAUwBNAEMAXABmAGwAYQBzAGgAZQByAF8AYgBhAHMAZQAu
    AHMAbQBjAAAAf/8EAA==
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload2</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPjQ3MUE4QUI0LUVB
    NjUtNEQzMC1BM0YzLURENjhFMEEwMjRBNTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMHMxPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XEVGSVxBUFBMRVxV
    UERBVEVSU1xTTUNcZmxhc2hlcl91cGRhdGUuc21jPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0PjwvYXJy
    YXk+AA==
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload2-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgABAAAAKAAAAAAAAAAA
    QAYAAAAAALSKGkdl6jBNo/PdaOCgJKUCAgQEWgBcAEUARgBJAFwAQQBQAFAATABFAFwA
    VQBQAEQAQQBUAEUAUgBTAFwAUwBNAEMAXABmAGwAYQBzAGgAZQByAF8AdQBwAGQAYQB0
    AGUALgBzAG0AYwAAAH//BAA=
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload3</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPjQ3MUE4QUI0LUVB
    NjUtNEQzMC1BM0YzLURENjhFMEEwMjRBNTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMHMxPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XEVGSVxBUFBMRVxV
    UERBVEVSU1xTTUNcTWFjLTdERjIxQ0IzRUQ2OTc3RTUuZXBtPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjwvYXJyYXk+AA==
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-payload3-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgABAAAAKAAAAAAAAAAA
    QAYAAAAAALSKGkdl6jBNo/PdaOCgJKUCAgQEZgBcAEUARgBJAFwAQQBQAFAATABFAFwA
    VQBQAEQAQQBUAEUAUgBTAFwAUwBNAEMAXABNAGEAYwAtADcARABGADIAMQBDAEIAMwBF
    AEQANgA5ADcANwBFADUALgBlAHAAbQAAAH//BAA=
    </data>
    <key>efi-apple-recovery</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPjQ3MUE4QUI0LUVB
    NjUtNEQzMC1BM0YzLURENjhFMEEwMjRBNTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMHMxPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XEVGSVxBUFBMRVxG
    SVJNV0FSRVxNQkE2MS5zY2FwPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0PjwvYXJyYXk+AA==
    </data>
    <key>efi-backup-boot-device</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPkRCOUFFQ0Y2LTg2
    QzYtNDcyOS1CRTk5LUM2N0MzREIxMzgwQTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMXMyPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XDFBMzk2RjBBLTlD
    NjYtMzVGMy05ODA1LTQ2RDBGNEZENjdCNVxTeXN0ZW1cTGlicmFyeVxDb3JlU2Vydmlj
    ZXNcYm9vdC5lZmk8L3N0cmluZz48L2RpY3Q+PC9hcnJheT4A
    </data>
    <key>efi-backup-boot-device-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgACAAAAKEAGAAAAAACw
    vxkOAAAAACCV+WedIUZClu42JCLFaBoCAgQDJAD3/HS+fAvzSZFHAfQELmhC9uya28aG
    KUe+mcZ8PbE4CgQEmgBcADEAQQAzADkANgBGADAAQQAtADkAQwA2ADYALQAzADUARgAz
    AC0AOQA4ADAANQAtADQANgBEADAARgA0AEYARAA2ADcAQgA1AFwAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0A
    XABMAGkAYgByAGEAcgB5AFwAQwBvAHIAZQBTAGUAcgB2AGkAYwBlAHMAXABiAG8AbwB0
    AC4AZQBmAGkAAAB//wQA
    </data>
    <key>efi-backup-boot-device-data-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgACAAAAKEAGAAAAAACw
    vxkOAAAAACCV+WedIUZClu42JCLFaBoCAgQDJAD3/HS+fAvzSZFHAfQELmhC9uya28aG
    KUe+mcZ8PbE4CgQEmgBcADEAQQAzADkANgBGADAAQQAtADkAQwA2ADYALQAzADUARgAz
    AC0AOQA4ADAANQAtADQANgBEADAARgA0AEYARAA2ADcAQgA1AFwAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0A
    XABMAGkAYgByAGEAcgB5AFwAQwBvAHIAZQBTAGUAcgB2AGkAYwBlAHMAXABiAG8AbwB0
    AC4AZQBmAGkAAAB//wQA
    </data>
    <key>efi-boot-device</key>
    <data>
    PGFycmF5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9NYXRjaDwva2V5PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9Qcm92aWRl
    ckNsYXNzPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5JT01lZGlhPC9zdHJpbmc+PGtleT5JT1Byb3BlcnR5
    TWF0Y2g8L2tleT48ZGljdD48a2V5PlVVSUQ8L2tleT48c3RyaW5nPkRCOUFFQ0Y2LTg2
    QzYtNDcyOS1CRTk5LUM2N0MzREIxMzgwQTwvc3RyaW5nPjwvZGljdD48L2RpY3Q+PGtl
    eT5CTExhc3RCU0ROYW1lPC9rZXk+PHN0cmluZz5kaXNrMXMyPC9zdHJpbmc+PC9kaWN0
    PjxkaWN0PjxrZXk+SU9FRklEZXZpY2VQYXRoVHlwZTwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+TWVkaWFG
    aWxlUGF0aDwvc3RyaW5nPjxrZXk+UGF0aDwva2V5PjxzdHJpbmc+XDFBMzk2RjBBLTlD
    NjYtMzVGMy05ODA1LTQ2RDBGNEZENjdCNVxTeXN0ZW1cTGlicmFyeVxDb3JlU2Vydmlj
    ZXNcYm9vdC5lZmk8L3N0cmluZz48L2RpY3Q+PC9hcnJheT4A
    </data>
    <key>efi-boot-device-data</key>
    <data>
    AgEMANBBAwoAAAAAAQEGAAUcAQEGAAAAAxIKAAAAAAAAAAQBKgACAAAAKEAGAAAAAACw
    vxkOAAAAACCV+WedIUZClu42JCLFaBoCAgQDJAD3/HS+fAvzSZFHAfQELmhC9uya28aG
    KUe+mcZ8PbE4CgQEmgBcADEAQQAzADkANgBGADAAQQAtADkAQwA2ADYALQAzADUARgAz
    AC0AOQA4ADAANQAtADQANgBEADAARgA0AEYARAA2ADcAQgA1AFwAUwB5AHMAdABlAG0A
    XABMAGkAYgByAGEAcgB5AFwAQwBvAHIAZQBTAGUAcgB2AGkAYwBlAHMAXABiAG8AbwB0
    AC4AZQBmAGkAAAB//wQA
    </data>
    <key>fmm-computer-name</key>
    <data>
    c3R1ZGVudA==
    </data>
    <key>fmm-mobileme-token-FMM</key>
    <data>
    YnBsaXN0MDDdAQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMDQ4PFhcOGA4ZGhscHR9fEA91bnJlZ2lzdGVyU3Rh
    dGVYdXNlckluZm9ZYXV0aFRva2VuXxARb3NVc2VyRGlzYXBwZWFyZWReZGlzYWJsZUNv
    bnRleHRWdXNlcmlkXWVuYWJsZUNvbnRleHRYdXNlcm5hbWVYcGVyc29uSURXYWRkVGlt
    ZVRndWlkXxASZW5hYmxlZERhdGFjbGFzc2VzXxATZGF0YWNsYXNzUHJvcGVydGllcxAA
    0xAREhMUFV8QFUluVXNlT3duZXJEaXNwbGF5TmFtZV8QE0luVXNlT3duZXJGaXJzdE5h
    bWVfEBJJblVzZU93bmVyTGFzdE5hbWVcWXVqaSBPa2FtdXJhVFl1amlXT2thbXVyYV8Q
    KEFRQUFBQUJaSE5laWdadGl5VUg4dlZ6Q3JDMnN1MmxadUoxNTZXc34JEQH1XxAbeXVq
    aS5va2FtdXJhQG91c2QuazEyLmNhLnVzWjgzNDQxNzE4MDEjQdZHNekcAypfECQzMzYw
    MkRERS1EMzI3LTRBRjYtOUY3MS03ODY2MzZERjM3NjOhHl8QIWNvbS5hcHBsZS5EYXRh
    Y2xhc3MuRGV2aWNlTG9jYXRvctEeINUhIiMkJSYnKCkqVmFwc0Vudlhob3N0bmFtZV1p
    ZHNJZGVudGlmaWVyVnNjaGVtZV1hdXRoTWVjaGFuaXNtWlByb2R1Y3Rpb25fEBNwMjYt
    Zm1pcC5pY2xvdWQuY29tXxAkRDQ0MDFGNEUtRkI3QS00M0EyLThCRUEtMDhFMUM2RDAz
    NjU4VWh0dHBzVXRva2VuAAgAIwA1AD4ASABcAGsAcgCAAIkAkgCaAJ8AtADKAMwA0wDr
    AQEBFgEjASgBMAFbAVwBXwF9AYgBkQG4AboB3gHhAewB8wH8AgoCEQIfAioCQAJnAm0A
    AAAAAAACAQAAAAAAAAArAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACcw==
    </data>
    <key>fmm-mobileme-token-FMM-BridgeHasAccount</key>
    <data>
    QnJpZGdlSGFzQWNjb3VudFZhbHVl
    </data>
    <key>prev-lang:kbd</key>
    <data>
    ZW4tVVM6MA==
    </data>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

It all looks pretty normal, as far as I can tell. Yours looks not dissimilar to mine. The data is encoding in base64, and decoded gives things like:

```
<array><dict><key>IOMatch</key><dict><key>IOProviderClass</key><string>IOMedia</string><key>IOPropertyMatch</key><dict><key>UUID</key><string>471A8AB4-EA65-4D30-A3F3-DD68E0A024A5</string></dict></dict><key>BLLastBSDName</key><string>disk0s1</string></dict><dict><key>IOEFIDevicePathType</key><string>MediaFilePath</string><key>Path</key><string>\EFI\APPLE\FIRMWARE\MBA61.scap</string></dict></array>�
```

Comment: No matter what I did it would just go back to something like this. Still does, I'm getting new computer.  The backlight would just continue to brighten and freeze the screen up.  Bluetooth was persistently opening up a usb connection and handshaking the the system to overtake the network and lock me out of the computer.  More and more memory allocating and it was impossible to get it out of the kernel memory.